# How to define constants dynamically based on database values?

Tags: php, constants, software-design

I am using `PHP` & `MySQL`, but this question is language-agnostic. I have an application in which there is a db table called categories which has `category_id` and `category_name`.

```
|---------------------|
| Cat ID | Cat Name   |
| --------------------|      
| 1      | Desktop    |
| 2      | Laptop     |
| 3      | Tablet     | 
| 4      | Smart Phone|
|---------------------|
```

In the code I need to make comparisons for these IDs in many places, so I defined them as constants so I know what I am comparing:

```
define("DESKTOP",1);
define("LAPTOP",2);
define("TABLET",3);
define("SMARTPHONE",4);
```

So now I use them like:

```
if($user_device == SMARTPHONE) 
{
  // do something..
}
```

As categories increase, I am having to `define()` them manually. Is this how it is usually done? Can I dynamically query the table and create a list of constants based on category name and id? What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, just loop through the database object/array and define the constants.

```
$categories = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
foreach($categories AS $category)
{ 
    define($category['category_name'],$category['category_id']);
}
```

But that's not really how a constant was intended to be used.  A constant is something that is ALWAYS constant, regardless of the database, or even the application.  For instance, PI is a constant. The number of inches in a mile is a constant.  The way you are using it should be a variable...

```
if($user_device == $category['smartphone'])
{
     // do something...;
}
```

Comment: It's not the end of the world if you use a constant that's not universally constant, but it is dangerous to create constants from the database, because there's nothing preventing the database from being changed except your individual knowledge that it shouldn't be changed.

Comment: I think the idea of constant is that it cannot change *during the execution of script*, not that it can *never* change (like PI). `const` in JavaScript is also used that way.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I dynamically query the table and create a list of constants based
>   on category name and id?

Yes, you can. If instead of using *constants* you use *variables*. Because constants do not change as explained [in the official PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php):

> A constant is an identifier (name) for a simple value. **As the name
>   suggests, that value cannot change during the execution of the script
>   (except for magic constants, which aren't actually constants).** A
>   constant is case-sensitive by default. By convention, constant
>   identifiers are always uppercase.

That is why *constants* are called *constants* & *variables* are called *variables*; *constants* are *constant* & *variables* are *variable*.

And “magic constants” are basically system controllable items like `__FILE__` or `__DIR__`. The values of magic constants can change, but they are not directly controlled by you but reflect system level changes.

That said in your case the solution comes from your variable naming convention. Meaning, there is something nice about the UPPERCASE of constants & makes them seem appropriate for your code’s needs. So just change your code to us uppercase variables:

```
$DESKTOP = 1;
$LAPTOP= 2;
$TABLET= 3;
$SMARTPHONE= 4;
```

Or you can just set an array named something like `$special_items`, and then set this:

```
$special_items['DESKTOP'] = 1;
$special_items['LAPTOP'] = 2;
$special_items['TABLET'] = 4;
$special_items['SMARTPHONE'] = 4;
```

Or perhaps if you wanted them available to the scope context of a class, then do this:

```
$this->special_items['DESKTOP'] = 1;
$this->special_items['LAPTOP'] = 2;
$this->special_items['TABLET'] = 4;
$this->special_items['SMARTPHONE'] = 4;
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the items in an associative array called `$items`, and give the key the name of the item and the value its ID.

Example

```
$items = array();

// Populate the array from the DB
while(...){
   $items[$db_items['name']] = $db_items['ID'];
}

//Condition
if($user_device == $items['SMARTPHONE']) 
{
  // do something..
}
```